# Svelte: Using reactive statement based on module context variable

Tags: svelte, svelte-component

I want to use code shared across multiple instances of a component to initiate code within each component.

I've attempted to do this using a reactive statement:

```js
<script context="module">
    let what = 0;
</script>

<script>
    export let number;
    $: if (what === number) [...]
</script>
```

But changes to `what` don't trigger a re-run of that reactive statement.

Why doesn't this REPL work, and how can I fix it?

https://svelte.dev/repl/38b94490982f4f3c80644fd364b50723?version=3.16.0

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Changing `what` to a `writable` seems to fix the problem:

```js
<script context="module">
    import { writable } from 'svelte/store';
    const what = writable(0);
</script>

<script>
    export let number;
    $: if ($what === number) [...]
</script>
```

https://svelte.dev/repl/f667f3eb6b7d453da1473d5e26268814?version=3.16.0

Comment: Using a store in a `context="module"` script is indeed the recommended way to do this. ["Variables defined in `module` scripts are not reactive — reassigning them will not trigger a rerender even though the variable itself will update. For values shared between multiple components, consider using a `store`."](https://svelte.dev/docs#script_context_module)